# Are these sconces from the 1920s or newer?

Tags: light-fixture, antique

I'm trying to determine if these are original to my 1920 house.
- They appear to be stamped brass which has since been painted gold.
- The wiring is cloth-wrapped.
- The switches are newer.
- The candlestick is a painted paper tube.

Thanks!
[image: Quarter]

[image: Back]

[image: Dissembled]

Comment: Is the switch mechanism bakelite or some other type of plastic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cloth wire in a fixture really is not a clue because many light fixtures use high temp wire like that today. I would take to an antique shop and ask them but the quality looks a bit less than the materials I have found from the 20' S and 30's. Specifically the detail work was much sharper/ cleaner looking.

Answer (score 3):

From the back it looks like stamped steel; dead give-away.  It is newer.

Comment: Older is usually cast pot metal.

Answer (score 0):

The fixture and cloth covered wires look old. The switch looks like a recent addition or replacement.